# Different City select field depending on selected country in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, html-select, checkout

In checkout I've made separate city selects for few countries, (their value will go to hidden default text field billing_address_1). City selects I did myself, they are individual.

I also use the popular solution to update all fields using ajax.
On change all works fine - when I change the country, all country selects are hidden, and the one city select for chosen country is visible, but it doesn't work on screen load.
I'll show only on 2 countries, but there's more, the code is the same for others - simply more fields to hide.

```php
add_action("wp_footer", "add_script_update_shipping_method");
function add_script_update_shipping_method()
{
    if (is_checkout()) { ?>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery('select#billing_city_ua,select#billing_city_pl').select2();

        /* DIDN'T HELP

         jQuery(window).on('load', function () { 
         var countryval =  jQuery('#billing_country option:selected').val();                    
               jQuery('#billing_country').val(countryval);      
       });

        TO COPY ALL STRINGS FROM CHANGE TOO
       */

        $(document.body).on('updated_checkout updated_shipping_method', function(event, xhr, data) {

            $('input[name^="shipping_method"]').on('change', function() {
                $('.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper').block({
                    message: null,
                    overlayCSS: {
                        background: '#fff',
                        'z-index': 1000000,
                        opacity: 0.3
                    }
                });
            });


            jQuery('select#billing_country').on('change', function() {
                jQuery('select#billing_city_ua, select#billing_city_pl, p#billing_city_field input').val('');
                if (jQuery(this).val() == "UA") {
                    jQuery('select#billing_city_pl').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex').closest('p').hide();
                    jQuery('select#billing_city_ua').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none').closest('p').show();
                }
                if (jQuery(this).val() == "PL") {
                    jQuery('select#billing_city_ua').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex').closest('p').hide();
                    jQuery('select#billing_city_pl').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none').closest('p').show();
                }

            });


            jQuery("select#billing_city_ua").on("change", function(e) {
                let cityval = jQuery("select#billing_city_ua").val();
                jQuery(this).find('.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper p#billing_city_field>span>input').val(cityval);
            });
            jQuery("select#billing_city_pl").on("change", function(e) {
                let cityval = jQuery("select#billing_city_pl").val();
                jQuery(this).find('.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper p#billing_city_field>span>input').val(cityval);
            });



            var first_name = $('#billing_first_name').val(),
                last_name = $('#billing_last_name').val(),
                phone = $('#billing_phone').val(),
                email = $('#billing_email').val(),
                city = $('#billing_city').val(),
                cityua = $('#billing_city_ua').val(),
                citypl = $('#billing_city_pl').val(),
                address = $('#billing_address_1').val(),
                postcode = $('#billing_postcode').val(),
                country = $('#billing_country').val();

            $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").html(xhr.fragments[".woocommerce-billing-fields"]);
            $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_first_name"]').val(first_name);
            $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_last_name"]').val(last_name);
            $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_phone"]').val(phone);
            $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_email"]').val(email);
            $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_city"]').val(city);
            $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_city_ua"]').val(cityua);
            $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_city_pl"]').val(citypl);
            $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_postcode"]').val(postcode);
            $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_country"]').val(country);
            $(".woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper").find('input[name="billing_address_1"]').val(address);
            $('.woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper').unblock();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php }
}
```

I tried many tricks - to trigger change event on body change, even on hover or scroll just for test. All country selects are visible on page loading, and when you select the country, all works fine. I wanted to re-select already selected value on load - using cityval too. To copy all the code from on,change code before xhr function didn't help. What's the right way?

EDITED - ADDED THE CODE
How I added city select fields

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'dropdown' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function dropdown( $fields ) {
     $fields['billing']['billing_city_ua'] = array(
    'label'     => __('City', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('billing_city_ua', 'Select your city', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide cities-select'),
    'clear'     => true,
    'type'      => 'select',
  'priority'   => 88,
     'options'     => array(
         '' => __('Select city', 'woocommerce' ),
        'City1' => __('City1', 'woocommerce' ),
        'City2' => __('City2', 'woocommerce' ),
        'City3' => __('City3', 'woocommerce' ),
        'City4' => __('City4', 'woocommerce' ),
        )
     ); 

   $fields['billing']['billing_city_pl'] = array(
    'label'     => __('City', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('billing_city_pl', 'Select your city', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide cities-select'),
    'clear'     => true,
    'type'      => 'select',
  'priority'   => 88, 
        'options'     => array(
         '' => __('Select city', 'woocommerce' ),
        'City1' => __('City1', 'woocommerce' ),
        'City2' => __('City2', 'woocommerce' ),
        'City3' => __('City3', 'woocommerce' ),
        'City4' => __('City4', 'woocommerce' ),
        )
     );    


     return $fields;
}
```

Comment: I added, I think that's all that can be connected with fields, no plugins for it

Comment: d-none, d-flex I think understandable, visible block with parental 'p', when select is, or hidden

Comment: More countries like if (jQuery(this).val() == "UA") {
                    jQuery('select#billing_city_pl,select#billing_city_xx,select#billing_city_xy,select#billing_city_yy').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex').closest('p').hide();
                    jQuery('select#billing_city_ua').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none').closest('p').show();
                } For now default city field is not hidden yet, but will be. Yes, now it's filled from the select of cities, which have to show based on selected country. The country select is default from wc- 'sale in 5 countries' option.

Comment: by css nothing is hidden yet, only that script that I show - d-none, d-flex. I want to show only one city select - depending on country. If it's the first visit of customer - that's a default value, to show its cities. If the customer choose something, it has to be the chosen country and its city select, All that city selects are separate,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have completely revisited your JavaScript code, and added some missing things.

Replace all your related code with the following:

```php
// Add custom city select fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'add_custom_checkout_city_dropdowns' );
function add_custom_checkout_city_dropdowns( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['class'][] = 'update_totals_on_change hidden'; 

    $fields['billing']['billing_city_ua'] = array(
        'label'         => __('City', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('billing_city_ua', 'Select your city', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide cities-select update_totals_on_change hidden'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'type'          => 'select',
        'priority'      => 88,
        'options'       => array(
            ''          => __('Select city', 'woocommerce' ),
            'City1'     => __('City1', 'woocommerce' ),
            'City2'     => __('City2', 'woocommerce' ),
            'City3'     => __('City3', 'woocommerce' ),
            'City4'     => __('City4', 'woocommerce' ),
        ),
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_city_pl'] = array(
        'label'         => __('City', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('billing_city_pl', 'Select your city', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide cities-select update_totals_on_change hidden'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'type'          => 'select',
        'priority'      => 89, 
        'options'       => array(
            ''          => __('Select city', 'woocommerce' ),
            'City1'     => __('City1', 'woocommerce' ),
            'City2'     => __('City2', 'woocommerce' ),
            'City3'     => __('City3', 'woocommerce' ),
            'City4'     => __('City4', 'woocommerce' ),
        ),
    );
    return $fields;
}

// Custom inline CSS
add_action('wp_head', 'checkout_city_dropdowns_css');
function checkout_city_dropdowns_css() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) : ?>
    <style>
        .cities-select.hidden {display:none;}
        #billing_city_field.hidden {display:none !important;}
    </style>
    <?php endif;
}

// PHP: Remove "(optional)" from some non required fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_checkout_optional_fields_label', 10, 4 );
function remove_checkout_optional_fields_label( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Only on checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() && in_array($key, ['billing_city_ua', 'billing_city_pl']) ) {
        $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
        $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
    }
    return $field;
}

// JavaScript: Show/hide City Select fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init' , 'checkout_city_dropdowns_js' );
function checkout_city_dropdowns_js() {
    $country  = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();
    $city     = WC()->customer->get_billing_city();

    wc_enqueue_js("
        const city   = '#billing_city',       cityUA  = '#billing_city_ua', 
            cityPL = '#billing_city_pl',    country = '#billing_country';

        var countryVal = '{$country}', 
            cityVal    = '{$city}';

        function showHideCityFields( city, cityUA, cityPL, cityVal, countryVal ) {
            if ( countryVal === 'UA' ) {
                $(city).val(cityVal).closest('p').addClass('hidden');
                $(cityUA).val('').closest('p').removeClass('hidden');
                $(cityPL).val(cityVal).closest('p').addClass('hidden');
            } else if ( countryVal === 'PL' ) {
                $(city).val(cityVal).closest('p').addClass('hidden');
                $(cityUA).val(cityVal).closest('p').addClass('hidden');
                $(cityPL).val('').closest('p').removeClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(city).val(cityVal).closest('p').removeClass('hidden');
                $(cityPL).val('').closest('p').addClass('hidden');
                $(cityUA).val('').closest('p').addClass('hidden');
            }
        }

        // On Start: Get country value
        if( $(country).val() != '' && $(country).val() != undefined ) {
            countryVal = $(country).val();
        }

        // On Start: Get city value
        if( $(city).val() != '' && $(city).val() != undefined ) {
            cityVal = $(city).val();
            if ( countryVal === 'UA' ) {
                $(cityUA).val(cityVal).change();
            } else if ( countryVal === 'PL' ) {
                $(cityPL).val(cityVal).change();
            }
        }

        // On start: Enable WooCommerce Select2 for custom select fields
        $(cityUA+','+cityPL).selectWoo();

        // On start: Remove '(optional)' from label
        $(document.body).on('update_checkout', function(){
            $(cityUA+'_field label > .optional').remove();
            $(cityPL+'_field label > .optional').remove();
        });

        // On start: Show/Hide city fields
        showHideCityFields( city, cityUA, cityPL, cityVal, countryVal );

        // On Country change: Show/Hide city fields
        $('form.woocommerce-checkout').on('change', country, function() {
            showHideCityFields( city, cityUA, cityPL, '', $(this).val() );
        });

        // For country 'UA', on city change
        $('form.woocommerce-checkout').on('change', cityUA, function() {
            $(city).val($(this).val());
        });

        // For country 'PL', on city change
        $('form.woocommerce-checkout').on('change', cityPL, function() {
            $(city).val($(this).val());
        });
    ");
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Comment: Thank you fforr the answer! I'm testing - all works fine with two countries, but when I add the third country to 'on start' section, it doesn't work. If I choose one of two firstly added and reload the page - I see its select, but when the third - no, its select doesn't appear.  I add another one 'else if' before 'else', and other things with coma -  randomly CZ,  cityCZ = '#billing_city_cz', function showHideCityFields( city, cityUA, cityPL, cityCZ, cityVal, countryVal ) etc, I didn't miss it.

Comment: I now try adding one by one, in the same very harsh order, not randomly, I think helps for now